# XAMPP MySQL error messgae, blocked port

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp, ports

```
Problem detected!
Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL"!
MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

Although i change the port in the my.ini file, it still doesn't work. Anyone who would know how to fix this? I get this error when i start MYSQL in XAMPP

Comment: Do you have two instances of XAMPP running?

Comment: And running XAMPP as an admin might do the trick.

Comment: Try stopping/starting Servers. If error persists, look in /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql directory and try removing mysql.pid / mysql.sock files

Answer (score -1):

**Quick Fix: Replace MySql folder from backup folder**

Go to xampp directory:

Stop all the xampp services

**Step 1: Create backup of *mysql* folder**

C:\xampp\mysql\data\ **mysql**

**Step 2: Replace mysql folder from backup\mysql folder**

copy *C:\xampp\mysql\backup\mysql*

past it in your data folder

C:\xampp\mysql\data (old data folder you already kept backup in step 1)

Start xampp services.

hope this will resolve your issue.